# Giving name to dropzones in ektron

Tags: asp.net, ektron

I wonder is it possible to give dropzone name, so when I open page in edit mode to see the name in header of a DropZone control?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to make a direct association without alterations to the code that would be destroyed during an upgrade. However, you should be able to show/hide headings for each by detecting when the page is or is not in Edit mode. For example, if you set a heading in your code like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="dz1Heading" runat="server" visible="false">
    <h2>Zone 1</h2>
</asp:Panel>
<PB:DropZone ID="Zone1" runat="server" />
```

Then you can show/hide that heading like so in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var myPage = (PageBuilder)this.Page;
    if(myPage.Status == Mode.Editing)
        dz1Heading.Visible = true;
}
```

That would make the heading invisible unless the page is in edit mode, in which case it becomes visible to the editor.

Comment: As I said, not without modifying Ektron files that would have their changes destroyed during an upgrade.